# Memory Leak while Using IabHelper (In-App Billing v3)

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, in-app-purchase

I've set up In-App Billing v3 on an app according to the [Google Developers page on that subject](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html). I'm pretty much following the same approach and steps from their TrivialDrive sample application (as can be seen, for example, [here](https://github.com/obriand/android-iabv3-trivialdrive/blob/master/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java)).

It all works OK (querying inventory, purchases, item consumption, etc. work) but I've been facing some rather annoying memory leaks.

If I switch the phone's orientation a couple of times, cause Garbage Collection, do a HPROF dump and analyse using [MAT](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html), I can see that a bunch of `Threads` are still alive and kicking, while they shouldn't.

[image: Android IabHelper causing Memory Leak?]

It's not a lot of memory, but it still accumulates in any `Activity` where I use `IabHelper`... And yes, I am disposing my `IabHelper` instance (hell, even set the listeners as null...) in my Activity's `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();

     (...)

     if (mHelper != null) 
        mHelper.dispose();

     mHelper = null;
     mGotInventoryListener = null;
     mPurchaseFinishedListener = null;
 }
```

Is anyone having the same issues? Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this? Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall, fruitlessly looking at my code over and over again and doing some more research I've found this question:

[Thread objects not garbage collected after being finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640390/thread-objects-not-garbage-collected-after-being-finished)

Apparently, the fact that these Threads aren't collected by the Garbage Collector is not related to a memory leak but instead to the fact that I'm running the app in `debug` mode. Upon running the app in `run` mode (still in Eclipse), Thread garbage collection takes place.

Furthermore:

> "The debugger and garbage collector are currently loosely integrated.
>   The VM guarantees that any object the debugger is aware of is not
>   garbage collected until after the debugger disconnects. This can
>   result in a buildup of objects over time while the debugger is
>   connected. For example, if the debugger sees a running thread, the
>   associated Thread object is not garbage collected even after the
>   thread terminates."
>
> (bottom of: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html,
>   as noted by @ptoinson)